# Where are the magnets on the samsung tablets

Tags: touchscreen

So is there a magnet within in the samsung tablets for the smart covers to work like the iPads or is it just on the cover it's self

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to verify this yourself? Bring something small and metallic near the edges of each to see where there is an attraction. Try a thumbtack, paperclip, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The magnets you are talking about, are on the smart cover. (S View Cover). The phone detects the magnet with a Hall Sensor.

Hope my answer helps